# Calling one activity from another and returning back behaves weirdly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have the following situation. I have an Activity A with three horizontal list views in which the data adapters are filled as and when required(not on onCreate or onStart). I also have some text views which have the same functional design. Now I call another activity B from A which is a video playing activity. Once the video is finished I go back to Activity A. Now this is when it starts to get weird. Activity A now has only the text views retaining the values. However all the lists are gone and invisible. I have destroyed the objects and removed all views in onDestory(). Ideally I want all my data to be visible when I navigate back to A - but I know this is not going to happen because at some Point Android will kill it. But how is that text views for which data is being filled from adapters is seen (retained) whereas the lists are gone. What part am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't quite enough information in that question to fully answer.  I would suspect it's when your loading content into the list.

When an activity is in the background, the process can be killed to recover resources.  In your case, that is likely what is happening.  When Android navigates back to the activity, onCreate is called again.  Views have a property called saveEnabled to reload state.  The TextViews have this enabled by default.  As for the list views, I suspect your not reloading the data to populate them and the state is not being saved.